# Convert unsigned char * to int * in Objective-C

Tags: iphone

I am trying to convert a `unsigned char*` to `int *` on in Objective-C on the iPhone. Is there any API that can help with the conversion?

Here's my best attempt:

```
-(BOOL)MyFunc:Version:(int *)nVer
{
   unsigned char * uszVerSize;
   //trying to assign string to int
   nVer =  uszVerSize[0] ;
}
```

Comment: Nice code in the first box :P

Answer (score 10):

Dear Lord, I think you have bigger problems than the one stated above.

You need to convert the chars to an int and return that.

```
return [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:uszVerSize] intValue];
```

You should also learn about pointers and how ints and chars differ in memory. You can't just assign a pointer to a char to a pointer to an int.

Comment: I just realised your return value was a BOOL, which I assume was success/failure. It might be a good exercise for you to work out how to check the result of NSNumber and return the value as intended originally.

Comment: hello

   Thanks for your quick replying. By mistake i written wrong code that is "nVer =  uszVerSize[0] ;" instead of that *nVer =  uszVerSize[0] ;.
Thanks 
KamalBhr

Comment: Um, that's still not a reliable way of converting from a chars to ints.

Comment: very useful thanks. Just wondering, to print out the value of an unsigned char, is there a way to do this without doing [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:uszVerSize] intValue] ? I've tried but 255 strangely comes out as 4294967204. Seems very strange since 255 should be the maximum value. I guess there's some default casting and conversion going on.

Answer (score -2):

```
const char *asciiCString = [@"abc-zABC-Z" cString];
  int cStringLen = [@"abc-zABC-Z" length];
  for(i=0;i<cStringLen;i++) {
    [asciiMArray addObject: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: asciiCString[i]]];
    printf("%d\n",asciiCString[i]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<cStringLen;i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[asciiMArray objectAtIndex: i]);
    printf("%d\n",asciiCString[i]);
  }
```

This is a code i wrote yesterday, to test some code of my learning face

It may look naive...but if it helps you....

asciiCString[i] returns you ASCII value of the char referenced at the index..
asciiMArray is a NSMutableArray Object